# TOC entries and labels for included PDF pages

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, table-of-contents, pdfpages

I am embedding full pages from another PDF document (using the pdfpages package), but I would like to be able to declare my own section headings before each embedded document (for e.g. hyperlinking / TOC purposes). pdfpages has an experimental feature which lets me do this, but the problem is that I want to put all of these embedded documents inside a section, so I need to insert a section heading *and* a subsection heading on the first document I embed. Unfortunately pdfpages doesn't seem to be able to do this. Is there a way for me to do this?

**Edit**: Thank you for the suggestions. I am also in need of something similar for general labels — at the moment I am abusing the `addtolist` option of `\includePDF` but the objects I'm labelling aren't really figures or tables.

Comment: Did you try `\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Title}`?

Comment: Invisible? I understand the text of your question that you wish to insert your own headings, which I would expect to be visible.

Comment: @Stefan: I can edit the documents being embedded to have the text of the correct heading, but what I really need is for \pageref etc. to work correctly.

Comment: I'd like to suggest a different title: _TOC entries for included PDF pages_ or similar. The adjective _invisible_ is misleading.

Comment: Your problem in _Edit_ is not clear. What needs to be labeled? I'd also suggest to create a new question for this.

Comment: @Christian: A point in the text in the embedded document, but I would settle for just getting the correct pageref.

Comment: @Zhen In my answer below, each page that goes into the TOC also gets a label that you can use as target in `\pageref`. I haven't tried to give labels to pages that don't go into the TOC.

Comment: Comment for people that receive the error `\phantomsection undefined`: you need to load the `hyperref` package.

Answer (score 39):

You can create entries in the table of contents (TOC) when importing a PDF. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents    
\includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={
     1,section,1,First Section Entry,p1,   
     1,subsection,1,Subsection Entry,p2,
     2,section,1,Second Section Entry,p3}]
     {publishing-logo+layout.pdf}         
\end{document}
```

Parameters for each TOC entry are:

- Page number relative to the first page of the included document. Caveat: with `pages={3-10}`, the smallest possible number would be `3`.
- Level for the TOC entry
- Depth of section (1 for section, 2 for subsection, etc.)
- TOC entry
- Label for the entry

You can create two entries for a single page on different levels (like `section` and `subsection`). In the example, the first two entries go to the same page. A label (like `p2`) can be used to refer to a page that is part of the included PDF.

Unfortunately error messages from `pdfpages` are not helpful when the above list contains errors. I encountered the following error, which was hard to spot:

- With `pages={3-10}` the first entry in an `addtotoc` record must be `3` or larger. It was `1` in my case but the error message wasn't pointing to it.

Comment: That was exactly what I tried to do, but having two entries for the same page didn't seem to work.

Comment: The third field is for the depth of the section. 1 for section level, 2 for subsection level ...

Comment: I don't understand the difference between the "level" and the "depth" parameters of the key. Besides I'm getting the following error (`Package pdfpages Warning : There's something wrong with the entries of addtotoc. Not all entries were processed.`) when compiling this piece of code : `\includepdf[pages=1, addtotoc={18,subsection,2,CV,cv}]{cv.pdf}`. The `.log` file isn't more explicit than that either. Could someone help ?

Comment: Just a guess: when you add a document of one page, you can't have a TOC entry for page 18 of it. Try `addtotoc={1,subsection,2,CV,cv}`.

Comment: yeah, `level` and `depth` confuse me, too. Sounds very redundant to me. What's the semantic of `addtotoc={1,section,2,Section-level but depth 2,p1}` or `addtotoc={1,subsection,1,Subsection-level but depth 1,p1}`?

Answer (score 24):

You could use the `pagecommand` option of `\includepdf`:

```
\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand={\section{title}}]{filename}
\includepdf[pages=2-]{filename}
```

Extend `pagecommand` as desired. The second `\includepdf` line includes the remaining pages without the page command.

You could also use the `pagecommand` option for setting hyperlink targets or bookmarks using commands of `hyperref` or `bookmark` there and also for `\addcontentsline` of `\addtocontents` if desired.

Comment: Ah. That's quite clever... but my first document has only one page. (I'm also having trouble with including multi-page PDF documents — not sure if that's a problem with my source material or the package itself...)

Comment: @Zhen Lin: then you can omit the 2nd line. Regarding other trouble with multi-page inclusion you could describe that in another question, perhaps somebody is able to help.

Comment: Genius, this feels like the slightly more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: I used egreg's comment above to avoid adding the text `title` on top of the pdf: `\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand={\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{title}}]{filename}`

Comment: this is SO clever! Thank you, what a lifesaver