# \input with undefined environments

Tags: input, include, standalone

I am trying to assemble my thesis with the standalone package.  I am attempting to input my old LaTeX document, lna_achemso.tex, into thesis.tex.

The standalone package works well when both documents have the same class.

However, my thesis, which is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
```

while the lna_achemso.tex is

```
\documentclass[
%journal=ancac3, % for ACS Nano
%journal=acbcct, % for ACS Chem. Biol.
journal=jpcbfk, % for undefined journal
manuscript=article]{achemso}
```

which gives the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment acknowledgement undefined.
```

I copied the files achemso.sty, achemso.cls, which contain the definitions for acknowledgement variable and wrote

```
\usepackage{achemso}
```

in the thesis' preamble but this does nothing.

How can I get the environment loaded?

This sounds so trivial but the solution eludes me.

-Dave

Comment: Standalone creates a single page document. The pdfpages package would be a better approach.

Comment: I think you want the `standalone` class.  There are numerous examples on this site.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** The only way to load the environment is to replace `report` with `achemso`.

Command `\usepackage` includes only the package `achemso.sty`, not the class `achemso.cls`.

Unfortunatly there are some commands and environments defined in `achemso.cls` but not in `achemso.sty` nor in `report.cls`. Those commands and environments won't work in a document that does not include class `achemso.cls` like yours:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{achemso}
```

In order to work in class `report` you should "translate" your document: you should replace commands and environments defined only in `achemso.cls` with their counterparts defined in `report.cls`, or directly `LaTeX` commands. Most of them can be replaced, for example `achemso` environment `acknowledgement` can be replaced by a `\thanks{`my acknowledgement`}` nested in a `\title{}`, or you can set up your own `acknowledgement` environment. Here is a MWE with an environment definition:

```
\documentclass{report}

\title{Paper\thanks{Hello world}}
\author{Me}

\newenvironment{acknowledgement}%       New acknowledgement environment
    {\large\bfseries Acknowledgement%
    \par\medskip\normalfont\normalsize}%
    {}%

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{acknowledgement}
Hello world
\end{acknowledgement}

\noindent\begin{acknowledgement}
\noindent Hello world
\end{acknowledgement}

\end{document}
```

In order to "translate" the document you have basically to repeat this procedure for every command and environment uknown to `report.cls`. Now `pdflatex` becomes istantly your best friend: it is sufficient to remove all the errors produced in compiling process. That's debugging.

Answer (score 0):

John Kormylo and Peter Grill,

I checked out [TOC entries and labels for included PDF pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15989/toc-entries-and-labels-for-included-pdf-pages) Unfortunately I cannot use pdfpages because it cannot create a list of tables and figures, which for a thesis of my length is not practical to do manually.

thank you RicoRally!

I solved this particular problem by replacing

```
\begin{acknowledgement}
 thanks everyone...
\end{acknowledgement}
```

in the original file with a simple

```
\section*{Acknowledgement}
```

which produces nearly identical output and maintains compatibility, so this particular problem was solved with ease.

However, some things are more difficult to avoid.

I have packages that conflict with each other:

When I do not have amsmath,  I get this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment align undefined.
```

which is easily solved with \includepackage{amsmath}

However, this causes an additional error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \dfrac already defined.
Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

which is boggling because that phrase doesn't appear in *any* of the files in my directory.

Also, I can't find the manual they're talking about, all the manuals I've seen so far are < 192 pages, and all the web pages that Google find with this error message are not in English....

I have no idea how to fix this. :,(

EDIT: This was fixed by removing \align{}, which was not necessary for the equation to display.

Lesson learned: keep packages to a BARE MINIMUM. There are often conflicts which make debugging problem like this very difficult.

Comment: I think you should use `\subsection*{Acknowledgement}`, which is what `achemso` uses. But, is very difficult to help you as you don't provide a test case.  It really would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.  This does not mean that you should post the entire `lna_achemso.tex`, but a reasonable facsimile that contains just enough to reproduce the problem.