# Content of including PDFs

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, pdftex

I have some little problem with my file. There are lot of included PDF files, without any `\caption` and `\section`. I need to create a table of content with these PDF files and function hyperref. Can somebody help me please ? 
my code below :

```
\tableofcontents
\newpage


\phantomsection         
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{something, name \textit{title}}
\shorthandoff{-}
\includepdf[pages=-]{upload/something}


\end{document}
```

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15995/3083 for how to use the `\includepdf` command itself to include a TOC entry. You don't need  any other command for that.