# Refer to appendix with \includepdf

Tags: cross-referencing, appendices, labels, pdfpages

I have included a PDF by using `\includepdf` into my appendix. I also added a label to that pdf but when I refer to it like `as you can see in Appendix \ref{mylabel}` it prints "as you can see in Appendix 4" instead of "as you can see in Appendix A".
Here is my code:

```
\tableofcontents

\include{1_intro}
\newpage
\include{2_chap1}     
\newpage
\input{3_chap2}
\newpage
\input{4_concl}
\newpage

\appendix
\label{appendix}
\newpage
\includepdf[pages={1},pagecommand={\section{appendixA}}\label{mylabel}]{mypdf.pdf}
```

Edit: My code after @Christian Lindig s suggestion:

```
\tableofcontents

\include{1_intro}
\newpage
\include{2_chap1}     
\newpage
\input{3_chap2}
\newpage
\input{4_concl}
\newpage

\appendix
\label{appendix}
\newpage
\includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={1,section,1,appendixA,mylabel}]{mypdf.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Now in the toc I have an entry at the end that calls "A appendixA" (which is good).When I reference to that pdf with "see appendix \ref{mylabel}" it says "see appendix A" (which is also good). I can click on that "A" so it jumps to the appendix. I can see the Appendix but it does NOT have a headtitle that says "A appendixA" (Which is bad)

Comment: The `\includepdf` command provides an `addtotoc` parameter to make entries into the table of contents. See this example: [TOC entries and labels for included PDF pages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15995/3083).

Comment: @ChristianLindig ok that almost worked. No it says Appendix A instead of Appendix 4, but when I click on the A it jumps to the right pdf at the end but it has no headline (I expected "A appendixA" as the headline) Can I choose a headline inside of \includepdf ?

Comment: Could you post your code? Do you want just a TOC entry and a label for the PDF or create a headline, too?

Comment: I want a TOC entry and the title in the TOC entry should also be the headtitle of that Appendix (it was the case with my initial code in the question). But the problem was that it said "see in Appendix 4" instead of "see in Appendix A". But in the TOC it said "A appendixA" and so was the title of that page. So it was misleading.

Comment: Since you are including full pages as a PDF, where should the headline go? Before the first page of the PDF? In that case a simple `\section{Title for PDF}` before the `\includepdf` should do (and you would not need the `addtotoc`). If you want the headline on the first page of the PDF, I don't have an answer, I'm sorry.

Comment: The answer of Heiko Oberdiek (below) does exactly how I want it. It prints the headline on the pdf and in the toc. When i refer to it, it says "A". (headline goes as A <headline> in toc and on the pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\label` is outside the group, `\section` is enclosed, thus the closing argument brace should include the `\label` command:

```
pagecommand={\section{appendixA}\label{mylabel}}
```

In the form of the question `pagecommand={\section{appendixA}}\label{mylabel}`, the curly braces act as group:

```
pagecommand=\begingroup\section{appendixA}\endgroup\label{mylabel}
```

and `\label` does not see `\section{appendixA}` anymore, but picks the numbering command before, maybe the last `\section`/`\chapter` before `\appendix`.

Comment: You described the problem right? Or is there somewhere a solution I dont see?

Comment: @Selphiron You have overlooked the first code line (= third line of the answer).

Comment: Oberiek Thank you, I overlooked the difference in brace placement.