# Attach publication at end of thesis

Tags: appendix

I have a publication which I am required to append at the end of my PhD thesis. It is a separate .pdf file and was not created using LaTeX.

How do I make LaTeX simply append that document at the end of the PhD thesis? Would it possible to \ref{} that within the thesis?

Comment: See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/263288/82917. How to *really*  do it might depend on your document class.

Comment: Are you having to supply your thesis as a PDF file? In my day we had to supply paper copies of the thesis whereby it was simple to put extra paper pages at the end. --- GOM