# Hyperlink in Contents not working properly with pdf inserted

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, pdfpages

I used pdfpages inserted a pdf as the last section of the main body of the article, and next to this section is the Reference.tex. The problem is, although the page number of the Reference section is correct, if I click on the Reference it would jump to my pdf article (the thing right before Reference section).

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

    \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
    \usepackage{pdfpages}

    \includepdf[pages=-]{pdfFile}

\end{document}
```

And the Contents:

```
Contents
1. pdfFile
Reference
```

My problem is not with the included pdf -- if I click on "1. pdfFile" it will correctly direct me to the included file; **my problem is with the Referece-- if I click on "Reference" it directs me to the included pdf still,** which is right before the reference.

Any ideas? Much appreciated!

Comment: Did you used this way : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15995/120578 (If not please give us a [simmilar] example that reproduces your problem to work with)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thank you guys! Please see my updated edits as above.

Answer (score 1):

According to this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15995/120578

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents    
\section{test}
\includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={
     1,section,1,Section Entry,p2}]{test.pdf}%p2 is the page 2 for this test          
\end{document}
```

This should point to the right page

Another option is according to the same post but @egreg's comment:

```
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section Entry}}]{test.pdf}
```

[Pesronally I prefer this that automates the page and doesn't need manually fix after addind text before this pdf that inserted]

In both commands Section Entry is the "title" we want for the section (see the linked answer for more)